# Let $a_n$ bounded and $b_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$ prove $\limsup (b_n)\le \limsup (a_n) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Let $a_n$ bounded and $b_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$ prove $\limsup (b_n)\le \limsup (a_n) $

I tried to prove it like this:

Let $x_m=\sup{\{a_n : n>m}\}$ so $a_n\le x_N$ for all $n > N$.

let $n > M > N$ then:

$b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum _{j=1}^N\:a_j+\frac{1}{n}\sum \:_{j=N+1}^n\:a_j$

$\le\frac{1}{n}\sum _{j=1}^N\:a_j+\frac{1}{n}\sum \:_{j=N+1}^n\:x_N$

$\le\frac{1}{M}\sum _{j=1}^N\:a_j+\frac{n-N}{n}x_N$

$<\frac{1}{M}\sum _{j=1}^N\:a_j+x_N$

so we get $\sup_{n>M}b_n \le \frac{1}{M}\sum _{j=1}^N\:a_j+x_N$

now let $M \to \infty   $ conclude that : $\limsup b_n \le 0 + a_N$

and  $N \to \infty   $ yields : $\limsup b_n \le \limsup (a_n)$

Is my proof correct , if not how to prove it ?

thanks

Comment: It is correct but you wrote the first line wrongly. Instead of $n \leq N$ it should be $n >N$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy i fixed it  thanks